# java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServiceAccountKey.json (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, filenotfoundexception, firebase-admin

I just tried to import firebase amdin sdk in my project.

I'm getting these following messages in android studio.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: com.lupin.ganzp.ticketfireauthmanager, PID: 7883
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lupin.ganzp.ticketfireauthmanager/com.lupin.ganzp.ticketfireauthmanager.MainActivity}: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /ServiceAccountKey.json (No such file or directory)

This is may simple code

```
const val relativePath = "/ServiceAccountKey.json"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() 
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        SDK_Init()
        Access_DB("newDB")
    }

    fun SDK_Init()
    {
        var serviceAccount = FileInputStream(relativePath)
        val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://<HiDE>.firebaseio.com/")
            .build()

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)
    }       
}
```

I already did almost things that I can do...

I tried like that

1. Path-1 = "c:\~to~ \.json"
2. Path-2 = "ServiceAccountKey.json"
3. Path-3 = "./ServiceAccountKey.json"
4. Path-4 = "com/lupin/ganzp/ticketfireauthmanager/ServiceAccountKey.json"

But, this code can not find my json file, although it really exists as you see this pic.

[image]

Below code shows the created file does not exist.

```
val name = File(".").canonicalPath
    println("Test $name")
    val file = File(name, "/" + "ServiceAccountKey.json")
    println("file path : " + file)
    println(file.exists())

    println(file.exists())  //false
    println(file.canRead())  //false
```

anyone who knows a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Android project and not a Java project - therefore the location of the file should be `res/raw` or `assets` (which both are directories, which are being copied instead of being processed)... else that file won't ever make it into the built package, resulting in error `15`.

just be aware, that it might be worth a consideration, to put a file called `ServiceAccountKey.json` into directories which are being copied 1:1... because that key can be easily extracted from there.

this behaves way different than with the `google-services.json`, because that file doesn't have to make it into the built package, because it is processed by the plugin and then added into the string resources.

Comment: You absolutely should not be using Admin SDK in an Android app. It is for server-side use only.

Comment: Hiranya Jayathilaka, Martin Zeitler // That's no problem. because that admin SDK in android will be used by only me. anyway, Maybe I know why this problem is happening. I appreciate you.

Answer (score 1):

There's the way I initialize the Admin SDK in my Java project:

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("project-credentials.json");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://mydatabase.firebaseio.com/")
        .build();
```

I keep the JSON file in the same directory as I've set as the *working directory* for the application.

Comment: I checked that and found that FirebaseCredentials is already removed. So, I have to use 'GoogleCredentials' firebase.google.com/docs/admin/migrate-admin Anyway, This problem seems to occur when applied to Android, not Java. I'm try to keep credential json into res/raw or something folder.